# How can I to run php script from powershell-commandline?

Tags: php, powershell

How can i setup my powershell to run php scripts in like a commandcall like this

```
php test.php
```

I'm able to do this on a server at work which I connect to by putty, but would be nice if I was able to execute those scripts directly from my own without having some server running. 
I also know about Xaml, which I don't like since its require you to refresh some browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming windows since you said powershell. You can just [install php on windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.php) but that means also installing apache or enabling IIS.

Or there's apparently a [built-in webserver](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) for command-line functionality that might minimize the amount of headache involved in configuring that stuff.

This might help get you going also:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.legacy.index.php#install.windows.legacy.commandline

Comment: There is no need to install a web server

Answer (score 5):

You can do all the stuff suggested above or ...

Go to [php.net](http://windows.php.net/download/) and download the php file stack for windows.

Copy the file stack into say **c:\php** or if you want multiple versions, say c:\php5 or c:\php7 etc.

Open powershell and type `c:\php\php.exe -h`, you will get the php help output. Yay you are up and running, whoot.

(Note: you may need to rename `php.ini.development` -> `php.ini`

**Advanced instructions:-**

Type `env` into os search (cortana) and select environmental variables.

Add your php location to path (c:\php) and create a variable **php** (or php5 etc) pointing to `c:\php\php.exe`

Now you can run php in powershell with `php` (`php -h` to test).

Note: while not the question, this also works in the git bash shell.

Comment: The `-h` option did not work for me until I added PHP to my path.