# Open an excel using php and command line/command prompt/ powershell

Tags: php, excel, cmd

I want to open an excel and then manipulate the content using php and command line/cmd or powershell.

I have this script already

```
$data = file("input.csv");
foreach ($data as $line) {
    $lineArray = explode(",", $line);
    list($XXX, $XXX, $XXX, $XXX, $XXX, $XXX) = $lineArray;

    echo $XXX.",".$XXX.",".$XXX.",".$XXX.",".$XXX.",".$XXX;
    echo "\n";
}
```

I'm just running it in power shell using this

```
php test.php
```

What I'm targeting to do is like this

```
php test.php input.csv
```

and I will remove the statically coded input.csv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964392/how-can-i-to-run-php-script-from-powershell-commandline

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.legacy.index.php#install.windows.legacy.commandline

Comment: If your question is about how to pass arguments into the script - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826718/pass-variable-to-php-script-running-from-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

I did this

```
php test.php input.csv
```

and used the input as an argument

```
$args = $argv[1];
```